# Can we use both drivers and physics properties at the same time

Tags: physics, drivers

Today I tried to make an animation of coin that rotates on the z axis placed perpendicular to the plane, 
When I applied rigid body constraint (active) to coin and rigid body constraint (passive) to the plane then changed the collision shape to mesh, it made a natural move of collision. But when I applied driver in z rotation so that it continuous rotates then nothing happened but when I checked the animated option then it just operates as driver command. 
I don't know whether it is a valid or a correct method to do this, just tried to experiment. 
I'm eager to know why this doesn't work and I'm not much experienced with animating stuff just a hobbyist, I'll like to learn more about this if someone explains.